# How to use OutputCache for a specific argument only?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I have this example of OutputCache.
My problem is that I want the page to be cached only if the `[id]` equals to `NULL`. In all other cases I don't want to have cache at all.

MyController:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "id")]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{}
```

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "edit",
    url: "edit/{id}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "asd",
        action = "Details",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify (and implement) the `VaryByCustom` parameter of `OutputCacheAttribute`:

**MyController.cs**

```
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByCustom = "idIsNull")]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg.ToLower() == "idisnull")
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"])
            ? string.Empty
            // unique key means it won't have a consistent value to use
            // as a cache lookup
            : ((new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the [id] is not a query string. See edit for routing details

Comment: @user1615362: I don't see it defined in the route `url`, so what's the problem?

Comment: This IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]) will always be true.

Comment: There are no QueryStiring params at all, I am using restful URLs and the [id] is a url segment.

Comment: @user1615362: once again....not according to your route. I don't see `{id}` _anywhere_ in that route, therefore it's either a POST value (in which case `Request.Form` should be used) or a GET variable (stick with `Request.QueryString`).

Comment: Right! My bad... I have provided the wrong route. Please see the edit to the OP.